# Java Date difference in terms of days

Tags: java, date

Could anyone please help me out for calculating `Date` difference in terms of no of days in an efficient way?

```
Date nextCollectionDate = dispenseNormal.getDispensing().getNextCollectionDate();
Date currentDate = new Date();
int daysDiff = currentDate - nextCollectionDate;
```

Comment: What exactly you expect? What are you getting? What is the problem?

Comment: I want to calculate difference between two dates in days.

Comment: Use Java 8's Time API, JodaTime or even Calendar

Comment: Another option is using the [`GregorianCalendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//diff in msec
long diff = currentDate.getTime() - nextCollectionDate.getTime();

//diff in days
long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) which is a very useful API for these scenarios

```
int days = Days.daysBetween(date1, date2).getDays();
```

or else you can create your own method and get the difference

```
public long getDays(Date d1, Date d2) 
{
    long l = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
    return TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(l, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use `LocalDate` in Java 8:

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.now().minusDays(1);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.now();
long days = Period.between(startDate, endDate).getDays();
System.out.println("No of days: " + days);
```

which as expected will print:

```
No of days: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use joda api

Below code should solve your query

```
 Date nextCollectionDate = dispenseNormal.getDispensing().getNextCollectionDate();
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    Days  d = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(nextCollectionDate ), new DateTime(currentDate ))

    int daysDiff = d.getDays();
```